# Extract an object manually using Mouse

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse, extract, polygon

I'm currently starting to learn OpenCV and I have a question:

Is there a simple way to extract an object from an image **manually** using a **mouse**? I'd like to draw a **polygon** around the object to finally cut it out.

Since I'm just starting I don't have any idea how to do that.
I already checked the "Grabcut" sample to get an idea about using a rectangle to select a subimage, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Thanks,
visi0nary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to select the polygon use [setMouseCallback](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback) to get a callback every time the user clicks on the image. Add each clicked point to a list of your polygon-points. To visualize the points so far you can use the [drawing functions in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html). There is also some sample code on how to use setMouseCallback [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/ffilldemo.cpp). You can for example let the user pick points until he presses a button or uses right click for the last point to finish picking.

To use the resulting polygon look at the tutorial [here](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/5). Additionally after this you could also use [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) to crop the image around the polygon.

Edit: Just realized that it is probably smarter to use [fillPoly](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) to create the mask.

```
vector<vector<cv::Point> > polygons; // draw function takes list of polygons
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
cv::fillPoly(mask, polygons, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

It seems the above code is not documented (however it works at least in an older version of Opencv 2.3.1). Another way of doing it is this:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3); // Image
vector<vector<cv::Point> > polygons; // draw function takes list of polygons
vector<int> polygonSizes;
vector<cv::Point*> polygonPointers;
for (int i=0; i<polygons.size(); i++) {
    polygonSizes.push_back(polygons[i].size());
    polygonPointers.push_back(&polygons[i][0]);
}
cv::fillPoly(mask, (const cv::Point**) &polygonPointers[0],  &polygonSizes[0], (int)polygons.size(), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly how I did it finally ;) I first tried fillConvexPoly but that was not appropriate so I switched to fillPoly. Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The documentation about fillPoly present a different set of arguments' types than the ones you put.
I'm confused because I cannot compile with what you wrote.

Comment: Yeah maybe they removed it in the newer versions. It works with 2.3.1. Anyway I added some code that should be according to documentation.